# How to automate Salesforce application using Selenium Webdriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

Trying to automate the salesforce application but it has verification code after logged in and couldn't able to find any solutions to automate verification code.Tried using cookies for existing browser session but couldn't able to automate
as it is always opening the salesforce application in new session.Kindly provide any other valuable solutions on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your IP to whitelist in Security Controls -> Network Access and the verification code step will not be appear anymore to your pc.